# Only new pages return 404 when trying to scrape - old pages scrape just fine

Tags: facebook, debugging, object, http-status-code-404

I am getting a 404 error when trying to have Facebook scrape my new url's. I have pages that are a couple days old that for some reason keep returning this 404 bad request code.

**Older pages from more than a week ago load just fine.**

Example - Older Page URL mattlambert.info/blog/pride-is-rust-on-metal/ 
Result - Response Code: 200 (I dropped the http : // because apparently I can only post one link here.)

Example - Newer Page URL http://mattlambert.info/blog/the-pharisee-in-me/
Result - Response Code: 404

There is not a 404 response code in the headers of either page. Yet, only the older one can be scraped.

Steps to Reproduce: Go to Object Debugger

Enter Both URL's into the field "Input URL, Access Token, or Open Graph Action ID"

Example - Older Page URL  Result - Response Code: 200

Example - Newer Page URL Result - Response Code: 404

Expected Behavior:  both pages should return a response code: 200. You can go to both url's and see they are both working. Viewing the source of each page, it is clear that there is nothing in the header that would cause this.
Actual Behavior:    Problem exists only for new blog posts I have created in the last couple days.  Linter tool says there is no data.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmattlambert.info%2Fblog%2Fthe-pharisee-in-me%2F